# Questions about a piece of code with templates, conversion operator and copy ctor

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

Two questions about the following piece of code:

```
template <class T> class A {
protected:
    T j;
public:
    A(T k) :j(k) {cout << *this;}
    ~A() { cout << *this; }
    A(const A<T> &a) {
        j = a.j;
        cout << *this;
    }
    virtual void print() const {cout << j << ' ';}

    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &os, const A<T> &a) {
        a.print();
        return os;
    }
    operator T() {  return j;}
};

template <class T> class inherit:public A<T> {
    T field;
public:
    inherit(const T&t) :A<T>(t), field(1+t) {
        cout << *this;
    }
    void print() const {
        A<T>::print();
        cout << field << ' ';
    }
};
int main(){
    inherit <int> b(3);

    inherit <string> c("asdf");
    string k="str";
    c + k;//error no operator +
    b + 5;//no error
}
```

1. Why does `inherit <int> b(3);` leads to the copy ctor of `inherit`? Why copy instead of making a new instance of `inherit` from scratch using the default ctor?
2. Why does `b+5;` leads to the conversion operator `operator T()` and why it doesn't happen with `c+k`?

Comment: `main` must return `int` in C++.

Comment: `b+5` works because `5` is an int and has a built in `operator+`. `string` is a template and none of the templated `operator+` matches `inherit<string>` and `string`.

Comment: But string also has built in `operator+`... @BoPersson Also, why does it need to cast with `b+5;`?

Comment: @kuh look exactly how `operator+` on `std::basic_string` is defined.  Also let us be lazy: include the surprising output (which should be all of it), what you think it means, and what you expect *explicitly*.  My mental C++ compiler is imperfect, and copy/paste/compile is work.

Comment: There is a difference in that `int+int` is built into the compiler, while `string+string` is from the standard library. There are very complex rules for templates, conversion operators, and overloading that makes the compiler not look for a conversion in the latter case.

Comment: @bope plus they (imho) screwed up: it was specified way way back, and I hope they'd do better.

Comment: `field(1+t)` causes `inherit<string>` to not even compile for me. Can you make sure your example compiles e.g. with Wandbox?

Comment: @yakk when placing the string related stuff in comment, the output is `3 3 4 3`, it can be compiled and edited here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b07a46a2cd6a28bf

Comment: @BillyONeal see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Why does `inherit <int> b(3);` leads to the copy ctor of inherit? Why copy instead of making a new instance of inherit from scratch using the default ctor?

Firstly, it does not lead to the copy constructor and the instance is in fact *made from scratch*.

The default constructor was not used because you didn't call the default constructor. The default constructor would be called with empty argument list (except, in this case, you must also leave out the parenthesis to avoid the vexing parse):

```
inherit <int> b; // this would call the default constructor
```

If you pass an argument to the constructor, then a non-default constructor will be invoked. `inherit <int> b(3);` leads to a call to `inherit(const T&)` which in this template instance is `inherit(const int&)`. It is not the copy constructor of `inherit`.

> 2. Why does b+5; leads to the casting operator operator T()

Because there is no `operator+(const inherit<int>&, int)` nor the analogous member function defined. Therefore, the overload resolution looks for alternatives to which the operands can be implicitly converted. It just so happens, that a built-in `operator+(int, int)` exists, and `inherit<int>` can implicitly be converted to `A<int>` (because it's a base) and `A<int>` can be converted to an `int` (because of the casting operator). And so, that operator ends up being called.

> and why it doesn't happen with c+k?

Firstly, you cannot even instantiate `inherit <string>` because the constructor tries to add an int to the argument string, which has no valid overload.

Now, assuming that constructor was fixed so that `inherit<string>` can exist, `c + k` still doesn't seem to work. I suspect that's because the string needs more conversions than `int` because it's not a primitive and you've reached the maximum depth that a user-defined conversion sequence can have. You can explicitly cast `inherit<string>` to `string` to shorten the conversion sequence:

```
static_cast<std::string>(c) + k; // this works
```

Comment: In his `c+k` example, `c` is an `inherit<string>`, not an `inherit<int>`.

Comment: Why is it `operator+(const std::string&, int)`? `c` is `inherit <string>` and `k` is a string.

Comment: @kuhaku & Billy, I read the code wrong initially. Answer fixed.

Comment: `inherit(const T& t)` would have been a copy ctor if it was `inherit(const inherit& t)` instead?

Answer (score 0):

> 2. Why does b+5; leads to the conversion operator operator T() and why it doesn't happen with c+k?

The compiler is complaining about a completely different piece of code. If you remove the + inside `main()`, you can see it still complains about an `operator+`:

http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/H3cUUaf8fSnbYDwA

The reason for this is on this line:

```
inherit(const T&t) :A<T>(t), field(1+t) {
```

you have `1 + t`, where `t` is `std::string`. `std::string` has no operator+ for `int`, so this does not compile.

Comment: It does compile: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b07a46a2cd6a28bf on VS15 too.

Comment: @kuhaku: It compiles because you commented out `inherit<string>`, not because you commented out the + statement in `main`. If you uncomment line 46 in your stacked-crooked example it will fail to compile.

Comment: While this bug makes kuhaku's example code bad, interestingly, if you fix the constructor, the code does reproduce the behaviour that was asked about. `c+k` does not find the overload.